# Excel VBA Error "The picture is too large and will be truncated" when closing file

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on this project for a long time and am suddenly getting a new error whenever I close my Excel file. I get the error twice "The picture is too large and will be truncated." There is no picture in my file. I am pasting formats.

This seems to be one of the Excel "Unsolved Mysteries".

I am using MS Office Professional Plus 2010 on Windows 7.

I have researched this and tried the following:

1. Deleted all %temp% files
2. Ran CCleaner
3. Set CutCopyMode =
   False after all paste special (formats)
4. Went to add/remove
   programs and reconfigured Office to stop the Clip Organizer from
   running. (Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features -> MS Office
   Professional Plus 2010 -> Change -> Add or Remove Features -> Office
   Shared Features -> Clip Organizer -> Not Available, etc.)
5. Rebooted

None of that helped, so I narrowed down the source of the problem by commenting out function and subroutine calls, running the program, saving and then pressing "x" to close. I did this until I found the right sub. Then I commented out all the lines of the sub and added them back in one logical chunk at a time until I found the problem area.  Here it is:

```
' *********** APPLY BASIC ROW FORMATTING FROM TEMPLATE ***********
' Copy basic row formatting from template and paste over all rows
wksTemplate.Rows(giHEADER_ROW + 1).Copy
myWS.Rows(lFirstRow & ":" & lLastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The paste contains formatting only - colors, borders, number formats, wrapping etc. It probably pastes on a range of 200 rows on average.
I have not changed these 3 lines of code in months. Why now?

Has anyone solved this mystery?

Thanks,
Shari

Comment: Shari, good work on narrowing down what's throwing the error! But since you haven't changed this particular section for quite a while, I'm wondering if there's something else that may be the culprit. Perhaps it's an "unsolved mystery," but I'm curious what code you _had_ changed before this error started coming up?

Comment: This is still happening to me, but sometimes it's not. I wonder if it stops happening after I periodically run the "Clean Project" function which I either got from MZ-Tools or from the Professional Excel Development CD (Can't remember which). I will have to try running Clean Project right after I see the error and see if it is gone the next time.  Still hoping someone finds the real solution.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error after copying a range and then using a set of pastespecial calls:

```
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

solution was to copy an empty cell and pastespecial xlvalues back into itself:

```
' to avoid the message on closing the book - "picture is too large and will be truncated", copy and paste a singe empty cell
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues

' clear clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have the same problem as you, but i have many pictures in my files...
Also sometimes i have slow down (open/close or just standard calculations(menu popup...)).
Usually when i close the workbook, and reopen it, it works fine again.

I have maybe some answer, not sure if any help :
Do you use Global variables ?

for example, in module 1:

```
Option Explicit

Public BigObject as AnyBigSizeType

Sub xxx() 'code following
```

try to avoid using global variables, usually its a mess and not even usefull.

Also, just to be safe, try in the immediate window :  activesheet.pictures.delete
(or even activesheet.shapes.delete , but this one also deletes comments and other stuff...)

Answer (score 0):

I get the error when closing a file after a macro used the `Range.Copy` command, even if the clipboard is empty. Doing `Application.CutCopyMode = False` is not enough, but adding this at the end of macros that use the `Range.Copy` method seems to be the solution:

This is my solution:

```
  'without this it will say "The image will be truncated because it's too large", because Excel is stupid
  [A1].Copy
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
```